# Spring @RestController not returning plain text response

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-4

I'm experimenting with the new Spring 4.0 @RestController to return a simple text response from a controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/heartbeat")
public class HeartbeatController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HeartbeatController.class);

    @RequestMapping
    public String heartbeat() {
        logger.info("Received heartbeat!");
        return "I'm Alive!";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    public String heartbeat2() {
        logger.info("Received heartbeat!");
        return "I'm Alive!";
    }
}
```

When I access /heartbeat then I get back:

```
"I'm Alive!"
```

The result includes the double quotes, what I did not expect.

When I access /heartbeat/test then I get a empty response back, but I expect the I'm Alive! text.

**UPDATE**

curl -i http://myserver.com/rest/heartbeat

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Server: Development/1.0
Date: Tue, 17 Dec 2013 18:59:08 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Length: 12

"I'm Alive!"

curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" http://myserver.com/rest/heartbeat
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Server: Development/1.0
Date: Tue, 17 Dec 2013 19:01:12 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Length: 12

"I'm Alive!"

curl -i http://myserver.com/rest/heartbeat/test

HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
Server: Development/1.0
Date: Tue, 17 Dec 2013 19:00:13 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Length: 0

curl -i -H "Accept: text/plain" http://myserver.com/rest/heartbeat/test

HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
Server: Development/1.0
Date: Tue, 17 Dec 2013 19:02:06 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Length: 0

Comment: Do you do this in a browser or from some other HTTP client?

Comment: i'm not familiar with Spring 4, but don't you need `@ResponseBody` anymore? i'm just curious.

Comment: Take the chrome debugger or firebug to post the full HTTP response, so we can see return codes etc.

Comment: @reagten, since Spring 4.0 if you add RestController on the class instead of Controller, you don't need to add ResponseBody

Answer (score 21):

I found out I was missing the StringHttpMessageConverter in my WebConfig's configureMessageConverters.
I was configuring the message converters to control the Jackson ObjectMapper.

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.setPrettyPrint(SystemProperty.environment.value() == Development);
    mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper());
    converters.add(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter);
    converters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter()); // THIS WAS MISSING
}
```

Comment: This issue may interest you then [SPR-11040](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-11040)

Answer (score 4):

@RestController is a convenience annotation that means you no longer need to specify @ResponseBody annotation on your methods.

But it will mean that your response type is being defaulted to JSON and therefore wrapped in quotes to be properly formed.

Comment: Do you mean @RestController does only support JSON responses? When I add products = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE I get a 406.

Comment: Your curl responses are curious, I haven't been able to replicate those here. heartBeat2() only giving a 406 if the request header conflicts with the producer.  For the quotes, could you have jackson in your class path and/or a JSON message converter registered?

Answer (score 2):

`@RestController` combines `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody` on your Controller class, as [stated in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-restcontroller).

When you annotate a method/a controller with `@ResponseBody`, Spring assists you with content negotiation, using the `Accept` HTTP request header and the `produces` attribute on your annotation.

In your case:

- You get an `application/json` response for your heartbeat action, because your HTTP client probably asks for that Content-Type and Spring did the content negotiation.
- You get a HTTP 406 for your hearbeat2 action, because content negotiation failed. You specified `text/plain` as a produces Content-Type on your Controller, whereas your HTTP client probably lists only `application/json` in its `Accept` request header.

**Update**: I've used the exact same curl requests but don't get the same results. Maybe a Filter or a HTTP proxy-cache is modifying HTTP headers?

Default format is text/plain:

```
➜ curl -v http://localhost:8080/heartbeat
> GET /heartbeat HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Content-Type: text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1
< Content-Length: 13
< Date: Wed, 18 Dec 2013 13:34:12 GMT
<
Hello, World!%
```

And with a `produces text/plain` attribute:

```
➜ curl -H "Accept: text/plain" -v http://localhost:8080/heartbeat/test
> GET /heartbeat/test HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: text/plain
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Content-Length: 13
< Date: Wed, 18 Dec 2013 13:39:07 GMT
<
Hello, World!%
```

[This sample application](https://github.com/TechEmpower/FrameworkBenchmarks/tree/master/spring) does the same thing and get good results.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for your answer. See my example requests and responses. I think the first /heartbeat example adds quotes to transform it to json... I don't understand why for heartbeat/test I get 406...

Comment: updated my answer with new curl tests. Do you have similar results when deleting `@RestController` and adding `@ResponseBody` on methods?

Comment: thanks for your extensive answers, much appreciated. Found out that I was missing the StringHttpMessageConverter.

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me. Please check the followings.

1. Ensure your DTO is serializable and has serializable fields, getters and setters
2. Check the dependencies for jackson. You should have

   - com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.1
   - com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.1
   - com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.1
   - com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:2.4.1
   - com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.4.1
3. Fix the RequesMapping Annotation:

   `@RequestMapping(value = "/test", consumes = "*/*")`
4. Check you have `<mvc:annotation-driven />` directive

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

1. add this in maven

   com.fasterxml.jackson.core
       jackson-databind
       2.4.4
2. make sure `<mvc:annotation-driven />` is configured in spring